# Как реализовать смену видимости блока по условию?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток!

Хотелось бы попросить у вас помощи разобраться в следующей проблемке. Есть замечательный простой код:

```
function extra (id) {
    $(".extra").css({display:'none'});
    $('#'+id+'').fadeIn(800);
};
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $({display:'none'}).css({display:"block"});
});
```

который при клике меняет значение свойства `display`, но вот туплю, как грамотно подключить `if` и `else`, чтобы при повторном клике значение свойства `display` менялось обратно.

**Обновление**

http://jsfiddle.net/SVgroup/5Lj6skxq/4/
В обрезанном виде некорректно работает, но суть ясна. Есть блок, в котором три ссылки, при нажатии на 1 основной блок расширяется и появляется доп. блок, при переключении на ссылку 2 появляется доп. блок 2 и т.д., а при повторном нажатии на любую ссылку доп. блок этой ссылки исчезает.

Comment: @SVgroup, соберите, пожалуйста, пример, воспроизводящий проблему на http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Долго мучаясь с кодом из первого варианта

function extra (id)
{
$(".extra").css({display:'none'});
$('#'+id+'').fadeIn(800);
};
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$({display:'none'}).css({display:"block"});
});

пришёл к такому

function extra (id)
{ if
($(".extra").css({display:'none'}))
$('#'+id+'').fadeIn(800);
 
 
else
($(".extra").css({display:'block'}))
$('#'+id+'').fadeOut(800);
}

и теперь блок при клике появляется и тут же исчезает, посоветуйте как доработать, что бы исчезал он тоже при клике, а не произвольно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот это какой-то странный код, удалите его:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $({display:'none'}).css({display:"block"});
});
```

А функцию можно написать вот так и всё будет работать как на отображение, так и не скрытие элементов:

```
function extra (id) {
  $(this).parent().find(".extra").toggle();
   $('#'+id).fadeToggle(800);
};
```

**UPD.** Обновил функцию extra, если элемент с id и элемент с классом extra лежат в одном контейнере, то всё будет работать как надо.

Comment: Этот какой-то странный код работает, а вот ваш странный код, отображает элемент и сразу же его скрывает. И в начальном варианте, код отображает на разных ссылка разные div, а у вас отображает все div при нажатии на одну ссылку....

Comment: Покажите ваш html, хотя бы его типовой кусок, для класса extra нужно правильно настроить селектор. И да, если код работает не как надо, это считай не работает :)

Comment: Ну вот теперь и в вашем варианте всё работает отлично! Только есть небольшой нюанс, скорость появления устраивает, но вот скорость исчезновения такая же, а как сделать, чтобы он исчезал побыстрее, .fadeToggle(400), например?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SVgroup/5Lj6skxq/4/
в обрезанном виде не корректно работает, но суть ясна. Есть блок в котором три ссылки, при нажатии на 1 основной блок расширяется и появляется доп. блок, при переключении на ссылку 2 появляется доп. блок 2 и т.д., а при повторном нажатии на любую ссылку доп. блок этой ссылки исчезает. И получается что ваш вариант работает только при использовании одной ссылки, а если начинаешь переключатся между ссылками то доп. блоки просто начинают появляться друг под другом.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lj6skxq/6/ Посмотрите такой вариант, исчезают блоки за 400, появляются за 800, при нажатии второй раз блок исчезает

Answer (score 0):

[@SVgroup](/users/24922/svgroup), onclick убираем из html и пишем следующее:

```
var extra = $('.extra');
extra.eq(0).show();
$('#center-menu > a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var curExtr = extra.eq($(this).index());
    extra.not(curExtr).fadeOut();
    curExtr.fadeIn();
});
```

В CSS для блоков .extra - **position: absolute;**, а для родительского - **position: relative;**. [Проверяем результат работы](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lj6skxq/5/).

Comment: @Deonis, вот зачем вы людям моск взрываете сразу вашим сложным JS, всё придёт со временем, а чтобы писать такой код как у вас нужно годика 2 на JS фронтенды пилить :) Ваш код да, будет прекрасно работать, но он просто не сможет его потом изменить при необходимости

Comment: MasterAlex так может быть вы подскажите, как добавить if и else в изначальный вариант?